# Dropdownlist in gridview edit template doesnt' update value of column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have a gridview that is bounded with a sql data source. After that I changed a edit template for one column and instead of textBox I used a dropdownlist. In that dropdownlist I entered two items and their values. Now when I update a gridview column where I installed dropdownlist doesn't update it old value to its new value but gets a NULL value.

This is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNeobrađene" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="sdsNeobradene" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowUpdating="gvNeobrađene_RowUpdating">
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
          <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Ime" HeaderText="Ime" SortExpression="Ime" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Prezime" HeaderText="Prezime" SortExpression="Prezime" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Telefon" HeaderText="Telefon" SortExpression="Telefon" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Napomena" HeaderText="Napomena" SortExpression="Napomena" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="SeminarID" HeaderText="SeminarID" SortExpression="SeminarID" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="TerminID" HeaderText="TerminID" SortExpression="TerminID" />
              <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="PotvrdaP" HeaderText="PotvrdaP" SortExpression="PotvrdaP" ReadOnly="false"/>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="v" SortExpression="StatusP">
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server">
                          <asp:ListItem Value="Prihvaćena">Prihvaćena</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Value="Odbijena">Odbijena</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StatusP") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" CancelText="Odustani" DeleteText="Izbriši" EditText="Uredi" InsertText="Ubaci" NewText="Novo" SelectText="Odaberi" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True" UpdateText="Spremi" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
          </Columns>
          <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
          <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
          <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
          <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
          <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
          <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
          <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
          <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
      </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsNeobradene" runat="server" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SeminarBazaConnectionString %>" 
          DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Predbiljezba] WHERE [Id] = @original_Id AND [Ime] = @original_Ime AND [Prezime] = @original_Prezime AND [Email] = @original_Email AND [Telefon] = @original_Telefon AND (([Napomena] = @original_Napomena) OR ([Napomena] IS NULL AND @original_Napomena IS NULL)) AND [SeminarID] = @original_SeminarID AND [TerminID] = @original_TerminID AND [PotvrdaP] = @original_PotvrdaP AND (([StatusP] = @original_StatusP) OR ([StatusP] IS NULL AND @original_StatusP IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Predbiljezba] ([Ime], [Prezime], [Email], [Telefon], [Napomena], [SeminarID], [TerminID], [PotvrdaP], [StatusP]) VALUES (@Ime, @Prezime, @Email, @Telefon, @Napomena, @SeminarID, @TerminID, @PotvrdaP, @StatusP)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Predbiljezba] WHERE ([PotvrdaP] = @PotvrdaP)" 
          UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Predbiljezba] SET [Ime] = @Ime, [Prezime] = @Prezime, [Email] = @Email, [Telefon] = @Telefon, [Napomena] = @Napomena, [SeminarID] = @SeminarID, [TerminID] = @TerminID, [PotvrdaP] = @PotvrdaP, [StatusP] = @StatusP WHERE [Id] = @original_Id">
          <DeleteParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Ime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Prezime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Telefon" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Napomena" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_SeminarID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_TerminID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_PotvrdaP" Type="Boolean" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_StatusP" Type="String" />
          </DeleteParameters>
          <InsertParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="Ime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Prezime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Telefon" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Napomena" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="SeminarID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="TerminID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="PotvrdaP" Type="Boolean" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="StatusP" Type="String" />
          </InsertParameters>
          <SelectParameters>
              <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="False" Name="PotvrdaP" Type="Boolean" />
          </SelectParameters>
          <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="Ime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Prezime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Telefon" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Napomena" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="SeminarID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="TerminID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="PotvrdaP" Type="Boolean" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="StatusP" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Ime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Prezime" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Email" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Telefon" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_Napomena" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_SeminarID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_TerminID" Type="Int32" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_PotvrdaP" Type="Boolean" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="original_StatusP" Type="String" />
          </UpdateParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there any other stuff I need to change so this could work ?

Comment: Change the ID of the DDL to StatusP and try agian.

Comment: This didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *Bind* your `DropDownList` to your database field

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server"
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StatusP") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Value="">None</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Prihvaćena">Prihvaćena</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Odbijena">Odbijena</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The key part is

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StatusP") %>'
```

This will cause the value you select to pass to your datasource.

Comment: Hello Kirk, after i did what you suggest i get this error - 'ddlStatus' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. I know where the problem is, but I am not sure how to solve it. I have a column in my database table that is empty by default. And when I edit, I need to give value to that column and that value can be only "Prihvaćena" or "Odbijena". My ddl is not binded with anything but it has two items inside with their text & value. When i press save I wan't selected value sent to That column in database, and it doesn't in my code from question :(

Comment: @Goran you can add a "None" column that will be selected if your value is empty at the start. I've updated the answer, but do let me know if there are other requirements for this field.

Comment: error diappeared after this but now it like in the beginning, after I press update, it send null value no mater what is selected in dropdownlist. I really don't know what is the problem. First time I am trying this, and I just wanted to change from text box to dropdownlist to restrict user from entering one of two possible strings... Maybe I am doing this the wrong way, don't know really :(

Comment: I made a sql table vith these three values from your example and binded like you did, and now everything works fine :) Thank you very much for your help.